# PHP 7.3.8. ZIP extension on MacOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: php, zip, configure, macos-catalina

I’m trying to use the builtin PHP in MacOS Catalina 10.15 by compiling the ZIP extension by myself.

In the new MacOS Catalina, the `phpize` tool is no longer usable since inside it contains an invalid path to the PHP libraries. The volume `/usr` is mounted read-only, making all the methods used in the past invalid.

I installed [Xcode 11](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/xcode/id497799835) from the AppStore.

Then I created another `phpize` that references Xcode by copiyng it to my Desktop

```
cp /usr/bin/phpize ~/Desktop/
```

then opened it for edit with `vim`

```
vim ~/Desktop/phpize
```

and modified line 8 as follows

```
includedir = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/php"
```

Then, downloaded [php-7.3.8](https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.3.8.tar.xz), the same PHP version built-in on MacOS Catalina 10.15.

After have unpacked the archive file in the Downloads folder, I opened the Terminal up to its folder

```
cd ~/Downloads/php-7.3.8/ext/zip
```

Once inside, launched the customized phpize in order to prepare the ZIP extension to configure

```
~/Desktop/phpize
```

The extension is now configurable. I launched configure with additional path to the required `zlib`

```
sudo ./configure --with-zlib-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/
```

The next step would be compile and install, but I’m still getting the error `php.h file not found`

```
make && make install
```

Maybe there’s still a wrong path somewhere...

Comment: Look at your `Makefile`. Might need to manually update some path there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CPPFLAGS` to point `make` to the right `/usr/include`, which is located inside `Xcode.app` :

```
INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

make CPPFLAGS="-I${INCLUDE_PATH}/php -I${INCLUDE_PATH}/php/main -I${INCLUDE_PATH}/php/TSRM -I${INCLUDE_PATH}/php/Zend -I${INCLUDE_PATH}/php/ext -I${INCLUDE_PATH}/php/ext/date/lib"
```

Also note, when editing `phpize`, there should not be spaces around the legal sign (`=`).

#### EDIT

To address the followup comment, `make install` will also fail because it can't move the extension to the right place. But you still need to run the command as it will sign the `*.so` file.

Once `make install` is run, move the executable somewhere safe. I use `/usr/local/php/extensions`.

For example with `Xdebug` (change the `.so` name to the name of your extension):

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/php/extensions
sudo cp $(php-config --extension-dir)/xdebug.so /usr/local/php/extensions
```

Then you edit the PHP configuration to enable your extension `sudo nano /etc/php.ini` by adding the necessary lines at the bottom (don't know the exact line for zip).

One this is done, restart the built-in server to be sure :

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Careful, disabling SIP is ALWAYS the wrong answer! `make install` will partially fail because it can't move the extension, but you can move it manually. See https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina#enabled-support-in-php and edit.